# Tiling curved 3D space

Tags: polyhedra, polytopes, tiling

A flat plane can be tiled, for example, with regular hexagons. If you try to tile a sphere with hexagons, however, it doesn't work--you have to introduce 12 pentagons to complete the tiling. Try to tile a sphere with triangles, and you can do it, but there will still be 12 defects where you have 5 triangles surrounding a vertex rather than the regular 6.

Meanwhile, flat 3D space can be tiled, for example, with truncated octahedra, or disphenoid tetrahedra. But what happens if we try to tile a 3-sphere? Is it known what kinds of defects will be introduced?

(I presume the answer will be related to regular 4D polytopes, the way that the 12-point defects in 2-sphere tilings are related to dodecahedra, but I have no idea how to convert that intuition into a proof of what the shapes around the defect points might be for different possible face tilings.)

Comment: Much like the 2D case, there are tilings with all kinds of defects.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Do you know where I could read up on them?

Comment: No. Why? They are easy to construct by hand. Also, just like you expected, they are related to truncated regular 4D polytopes, which are all there in Wikipedia.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Given that it is not at all obvious that truncated octahedrons tile space in the first place, and visualizing 4D structures is *hard*, I must dispute the claim that they are "easy" to construct by hand!

Comment: OK, maybe "easy" was an overstatement.